# Thirteen in a row

Tags: word, pattern

Replace the X's.

There are thirteen entries in total. Words only.
Spacing between the words are either 1, 5 or 30 (I'm sure it's easy to distinguish one from the other). The exact spacing itself is not important, just to indicate separation. Also, I've giving you the first letter of each entry.

One more thing; Your answer should be really close to the answer, so don't waste your time and immediately go look for your answer!

---

```
SXXXXX EXXXXXXX     HXXXXXXXX BXXXXXXXXX PXXXXXXXXXX XXXX IXXXX     NXXXXXXX XXXX BXXXXXXX XXXX HXXXXXX HXXXXXXXXX XXXX     UXXX RXXX                               MXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXX
```

---

Hint 1

> One more thing; **Your Answer** should be really close to the answer, so don't waste your time and immediately go look for **Your Answer**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ooh, I like this one

> In order, from left to right:
>  `Strong Emphasis     Hyperlink Blockquote Preformatted Text Image   Numbered List Bulleted List Heading Horizontal Rule     Undo Redo   Markdown Editing Help`  
>  Those are all the names of the icons situated above the input area when writing an answer to a question

Comment: Well done! Your Answer is correct.